# Ionic 4 FCM.onNotification not called on iOS if app is killed

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4

i am struggling with an issue for weeks now with FCM push notifications on iOS. The problem is that if the app is in killed state when the notification is clicked, the fcm.onNotification callback is not fired.
Checked cases :

- iOS - App in foreground - notification popup not shown, correct code running : OK
- iOS - App running in background - notification popup shown - notification clicked - correct code running : OK
- iOS - App killed by OS / manually swiped away - notification popup shown - notification clicked - app opens - platform.ready runs correctly - **onNotification not fired.**

On android all is working fine.

I have tried setting everything in the notification i could google up :

- force-start : "1"
- content_available : true
- priority : "high"
- click_action : "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"

Code which should run :

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    alert("This alert is shown");
    this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
        alert("This alert is not shown");
        if (data.wasTapped) {
            alert('Received in background');
            self.router.navigate([data.landing_page, data.content]);
        } else {
            alert('Received in foreground');
            self.router.navigate([data.landing_page, data.content]);
        }
    });     
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made iOS background notifications work with `content-available: 1` set in the aps payload and testing in the service whether the `additionalData.foreground` value is false.

Comment: :sir can you tell me how to set aps payload and additionalData.foreground value ?

Comment: @Kapilsoni Please post a new question, you may reference me in a comment below your new question. There is not enough information here to answer you.

Comment: i have already post new question check below link: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62410530/ionic-3-onnotification-not-fire-in-foreground-in-ios

Comment: Posted an answer.

Comment: content-available:1 ur answer?

Comment: Do you use fcm? then you must make sure that the registration id the device gives you is one of fcm not apns. in config.xml of cordova add `<resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />` to the ios section. this file is from fcm, it will configure ios to use the proper push service

Comment: i am using fcm-with-dependecy-updated plugin but i have not added. <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" /> in the config.xml.can i add to ios section?