# IONIC 3: onNotification not fire in foreground in IOS?

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have implemented push notification in ionic Everything working fine on android and but in IOS got different scenario:

1. in foreground : onNotification is not fired as well as android working perfect.
2. Background: push notification is received but after tap from notification nothing happend

**app.component.ts**

```js
this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
if(data.wasTapped){
  console.log(data.wasTapped);
     //redirectPageViaNotificationType for redirect page...
     this.redirectPageViaNotificationType(data);
}  else {
    //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified
      // if application open, show
    let confirmAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: (<any>data).title,
      message: (<any>data).body,
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Ignore',
        role: 'cancel'
      },{
        text: 'View',
        handler: () => {
            //redirectPageViaNotificationType for redirect page...
          this.redirectPageViaNotificationType(data);
        }
      }]
    });
    confirmAlert.present();
}
});
```

when any push notification is received its showing notification when my application is closed or background it does not executing the this.fcm.onNotification()function. And i just debug this issue and noticed this, in my xcode console its showing:

[image]

**Tried Solution**

Link :

1. Add **"content_available":true** in the notification payload but its not working for me.

   https://forum.cometchat.com/t/ionic-push-notification-not-triggered-when-in-foreground-ios/620/8
2. remove Below plugin :

   **npm i cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated and local-notification plugin** and add it again but not worked for me.

   can any one please tell me why its happing and what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time on this problem, but I could not get the fcm plugin to work stably in ios. This problem was reproduced when the application was killed. I think the fcm plugin does not work too well with ios. I was trying to use phonegap-plugin-push and everything is working fine. This plugin can work with fcm and apns, and notification caught even when the ios application was killed.

Comment: sir i have update plugin version now notification is received in xcode log but notification not appear in the mobile any idea sir why not showing in device?

Comment: Notification should not be displayed if the application is running in the foreground, or the notification does not appear when the application is closed?

Comment: ok sir i agree with you but why its not showing if i am in background now app is not closed?

Comment: Do you keep using the fcm plugin? How you send push notifications? Can you try send notifications from firebase console?

Comment: yes i used fcm plugin.i will sent push notifications from firebase console via device token working perfect but not received in mobile ?

Comment: sir i got issue after using phonegap-plugin push >>>                                               
  Failed to restore plugin "phonegap-plugin-push" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin16/rbconfig.rb:213:

Comment: Have you tried to find solutions on your own? This seems like a bug from this thread and this doesn't seem like a plugin problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711249/how-to-solve-insecure-world-writable-dir-usr-in-path-mode-040777-warning-on-rub/26718467

Comment: yes i tried but phonegap-plugin-push  required cocapods 1.1.1 but i am not able to install cocapods1.1.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the requests, ie not just process some data in the background as you would with `content-available: '1'`, you must leave it as `content-available: '0'`.

I process Push notifications with PHP and Kreait/Firebase. Then for iOS this is my config:

```
  $notification = Notification::fromArray([
    'title' => $title,
    'body'  => $message,
  ]);

  $data = MessageData::fromArray([
    'some_key' => $value,
  ]);

  $apnsConfig = ApnsConfig::fromArray([
    'payload' => [
      'aps' => [
        'badge' => 1,
        'content-available' => 0,
        'notId' => UUID::v4()
      ],
    ],
  ]);

  $cloudMessage = CloudMessage::new()
    ->withNotification($notification)
    ->withData($data)
    ->withApnsConfig($apnsConfig);

  $apnsResult = self::$messaging->sendMulticast($cloudMessage, $iosTokens);
```

You can find the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging. For Android I used curl however, there was some problem back then with kreaits' fcm implementation. They did publish a new release that I ment to check whether it fixed this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: are u fixed above issue after add aps array ?